# How to Subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout with Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm using a UICollectionView with Storyboard and trying to subclass the UICollectionViewFlowLayout but it doesn't seem to work.

I've created the subclass `CollectionViewFlowLayout` :

```
#import "CollectionViewFlowLayout.h"

@implementation CollectionViewFlowLayout

-(id)init
{
    NSLog(@"Init of CollectionViewFlowLayout");

    if (!(self = [super init])) return nil;
    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(250, 250);
    return self;
}

@end
```

And in the Storyboard's Identity Inspector I changed the class for the flow layout:

[image: Identity Inspector for Storyboard]

But when I save/build/run, the itemSize is not set at 250 and my NSLog isn't being output.

I've seen in [examples such as this](https://github.com/AshFurrow/UICollectionViewFlowLayoutExample/blob/master/UICollectionViewFlowLayoutExample/AFViewController.m) that you can set the layout in the collectionView controller, but I sort of assumed that wasn't necessary if you set it in the storyboard.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Objects loaded from the storyboard use `initWithCoder:`, not `init`. Move your setup code there instead, or have a common method that is called from each initialiser.